# How to configure xml Report in jenkins

Tags: python, testing, jenkins, report

I am trying test my python script using jenkins.Issue I am facing is with the test report generation

I have created a folder 'test_reports' in my jenkins workspace.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PythonTest\test_reports

But then when I run the script from jenkins I get the error as,
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?

How do I actually configure the test report? Is the xml file generated automatically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please share the jenkins console output here?

Answer (score 0):

This was an expected result because,The script file I wrote was not a unit-test module.It was just a normal python file(It wasn't supposed to create any XML results).

Once I created the script using unit-test framework and import the xml runner,I was able to generate the xml files of the result.